# Magento2 Install extension from multiple-extensions repository

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer

I want to modify one extension from public `GitHub` repository(fork), and install it to my Magento2 via `composer`.

Extensions stored here [GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples). Really, i need only one `sample-external-links`. I tried many times to configure composer.json in my Magento2 root, but it doesn't work, i receive errors:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>     The "https://api.github.com/repos/magento/magento2-samples/sample-external-links" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

How to configure composer to install only 1 package from some repository like that?

my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.1.0",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.0",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento/sample-bundle-all": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": [
    {       "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/sample-external-links"
    }
],
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

Comment: because it's just folder, not a repo

Answer (score 1):

Each sample is packaged and available individually at **repo.magento.com** (The external sample isn't available individually). For convenience and demonstration of them bundling of modules, they have included the **sample-bundle-all** composer metapackage. Including this dependency in your Magento project is the more convenient way to integrate the full set of examples.

So to install the sample-bundle-all, run this command in your root installation folder.

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com/
```

Add the following code in the composer.json under the **require** section.

```
"magento/sample-bundle-all": "*"
```

And run:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
composer install && composer update -vv && 
php -r "opcache_reset();"
mage cache:flush &
mage setup:static-content:deploy && 
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```